# Repl.it javascript classroom - infinite loop

Tags: javascript

Apologies (& thanks) in advance for this - Im sure its me, but would really appreciate some other viewpoints if poss.

Repl.it has a number of JS classroom tests - after 2 weeks of learning by doing with JS thought i'd start right at the beginning for the sake of it...anyhow when i run my 'answer' code against their built in tests it fails them all... despite appearing to satisfy the tests.  This is my code

```
function doYouPlayTheTheremin(name){
  var str = name;
    if (str.charAt(0) === 'S' || str.charAt(0) === 's') {
    return (str + ' plays the Theremin!');
  }
  else {
    return (str + ' does not play the Theremin!');
  }
}
```

the repl.it fails it as follows:

failed these tests:
returns_a_string_value
returns_proper_string_if_1st_char_is_an_S
returns_proper_string_if_1st_char_is_an_s
returns_proper_string_when_1st_char_is_not_an_s

When I check the details tab it says:
Failed tests
Your program took too long to execute.
Make sure that it isn't waiting for input and that there is no infinite loop.

Can somebody tell me where Im going wrong here???
Thanks in advance!!
Mat

Comment: Could you please give us the description of the task -- maybe you've misinterpreted it! :)

Comment: Your code looks correct. Most people would leave out the parenthesis around the return value and directly access `name.charAt(0)` etc. and remove `var str = name`. But those are stylistic changes only.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - all fixed - was a bug-let in the platform yesterday but all is good now.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

CEO of Repl.it here -- this was a bug that's now fixed  -- sorry about that.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the swift reply - everything was working this morning when I tried again...repl.it had even saved my previous code, which was a bonus!